# How to create span content on mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a slider with content. but the content should appear only when mouse hover. This is the code I'm using:

```
<div id="slideshow" style="width:560px; background:#999;">
    <div id="slidesContainer">            
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="js/1.jpg" />
        <div> some text </div>
      </div>        
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="js/2.jpg" />       
      <div> some text </div>  
    </div>        
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="js/3.jpg" />
      <div> some text </div>
      </div>        
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="js/4.jpg" />
      <div> some text </div>
      </div>        
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the jquery 1.8.3 lib and this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var currentPosition = 0;
      var slideWidth = 560;
      var slides = $('.slide');
      var numberOfSlides = slides.length;

      // Remove scrollbar in JS
      $('#slidesContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');

      // Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div
      slides
        .wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>')
        // Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
        .css({
          'float' : 'left',
          'width' : slideWidth
        });

      // Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
      $('#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);


      // Hide left arrow control on first load
      manageControls(currentPosition);



      // manageControls: Hides and Shows controls depending on currentPosition
      function manageControls(position){
                if(position >= 4)
                {
                    position=0;
                    currentPosition=0;
                }
        // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
        if(position==0){ $('#leftControl').hide() } else{ $('#leftControl').show() }
        // Hide right arrow if position is last slide
        if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('#rightControl').hide() } else{ $('#rightControl').show() }
      } 

      function Aplay(){
        // Determine new position
        currentPosition =  currentPosition+1 ;

        // Hide / show controls
        manageControls(currentPosition);
        // Move slideInner using margin-left
        $('#slideInner').animate({
          'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
        });
          setTimeout(function(){Aplay();},2000);
      }
      setTimeout(Aplay(),20000);

});
```

now the `<div> some text </div>` should appear only when mouse hover, example: http://www.backslash.gr/demos/contenthover-jquery-plugin/#demo4

Comment: _“but the content should appear only when mouse hover”_ – then _hide_ it initially, and _show_ it only on hover (instead of dynamic _creation_ on hover).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
  .title {visibility:hidden;}
</style>
```

HTML add a class `title` to all needed DIV elements

```
<div class="title"> some text </div>
```

Add this to your script

```
$('#slideInner').mouseover(function() {
    $('#slideInner .title').css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$('#slideInner').mouseout(function() {
    $('#slideInner .title').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

Working [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/raqiyewi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: its working in jsbin but when i apply in html its not working.. only for the first image only Text1 appears when mouse hover

Comment: @user3419304 Well, it's all fine here. Have you added `class="title"` to all needed DIVs ? Otherwise, build a jsBin and I'll check it, no problem

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to set up your 'slide' divs like this:

```
<div class="slide" onMouseOver="$('#TEXT1').css('display','block')" onMouseOut="$('#TEXT1').css('display','none')">
  <img src="js/1.jpg" />
  <div id="TEXT1" style="display:none;"> some text </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy and i think this is the **fastest solution**, because require less jquery than the others (= keep your code clean)

1. Add the following class to every `div` which contain the description: `class="slide-desc"` to your HTML
2. Add `var slideDesc = $('.slide-desc');` to your JS, which is just to fit your way of write jQuery, **and** `slideDesc.hide();` (or `$('.slide-desc').hide;`, to use a faster way instead). This statement (it's better to call the `.hide()` method in first line of your JS, to avoid the description flashing while page is loading. Put it just after your declaration of variables.
3. Add somewhere in the JS these lines:

   ```
   $('#slidesContainer').hover(function(){
        slideDesc.show();
     });
   ```
4. You've done! **:D**

Comment: By the way, I like your avatar :)